# Grainy images in iPhone app?

Tags: ios

I made a huge version of my app's logo thats 15,000px by 15,000px. However when I put it in an image view with content mode `aspect fit` the image still appears grainy when running my app on an iPhone. Here's a small part of the screen:

[image: img]

Does anybody know how to make images sharp on iOS?

Comment: Have you tried naming the image asset "whatever@2x.png"?  This will signal to UIKit that the image should be rendered one image pixel to one retina display pixel, rather than one image pixel to every two retina display pixels.  Edit:  Actually this really just has to do with how you fetch the image.  One way or another you probably want your `UIImage` object to report a `size` that's smaller than the actual number of pixels in the image, if you want it to render sharply.